# How to find the lowest value of an array?

Tags: php

The result of `print_r($data['SearchAvailResponse']['Hotel'])` :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [HotelNo] => 1    
            [HCode] => IDJKT_00085
            [Name] => Cebu Grand Hotel       
            [Currency] => USD
            [TotalRate] => 56          
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [HotelNo] => 2          
            [HCode] => IDJKT_00094
            [Name] => Best Western Plus Lex Cebu        
            [Currency] => USD
            [TotalRate] => 65       
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [HotelNo] => 3           
            [HCode] => IDJKT_00102
            [Name] => Best Western Sand Bar           
            [Currency] => USD
            [TotalRate] => 93
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [HotelNo] => 4           
            [HCode] => IDJKT_00106
            [Name] => Goldberry Suites & Hotel           
            [Currency] => USD
            [TotalRate] => 51     
        )
)
```

TotalRate tag is hotel price

I want to find the lowest price of all hotels

How do I find the lowest price of all hotels?

Any help much appreciated

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$cheapesthotel = array();
foreach($data['SearchAvailResponse']['Hotel'] as $hotel){
    if($cheapesthotel == array()){
        $cheapesthotel = $hotel;
    } elseif ($hotel['TotalRate'] < $cheapesthotel['TotalRate']){
        $cheapesthotel = $hotel;
    }
}
```

Comment: I need you help. Look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38517387/how-to-multiply-number-until-achieve-single-digit-numbers-and-counting-the-numbe

Answer (score 0):

```
function getMin($array)
{
$currentMin = 10000; 
$minObject = Array();
foreach($array as $val)
{
    if($val[totalRate] < $currentMin)
    {
        $minObject = $val;
    }


}

return minObject;
}
```